# Lets Play A Little Game!! Why am I getting an Uncaught Type Error? :)

Tags: javascript, module, scope, global-variables, prototype

```
var Logistics = function () {}
Logistics.prototype.addItem = function () {
  console.log("item added");
}



(function(){
    // Place the above code underneath my comment
    // We now get the desired result Why?

    console.log("inside internal module");
    var myLogistics = new Logistics();

    var originalAddItem = myLogistics.addItem;
    myLogistics.addItem = function () {
        originalAddItem.apply(this,[]);
        console.log("another item added");
    }

    myLogistics.addItem();  

}());
```

Expected Console Output: -

> inside internal module
>
> item added
>
> another item added

Actual Console Output

> inside internal module
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

FYI: I will post the answer in 5 Hours if nobody has got it

Comment: I don't know why, but it works fine when you instantiate it in global scope or when you wrap class and prototype item in another self-invoking.

Comment: @Quentin Your answer is to mark this "question" as a dupe - dry humor :D

Comment: Took me 6 hours to figure out and that was with searching in stack overflow with no joy.

Good spot!

Comment: That was a great thing to know